# How to prevent Hibernate from making the id column auto-incremental?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want my ID column to be a String, then assign the ID myself at a certain point (prior to saving the object). However, when I set the class property as private String id, hibernate just ignores that and ends up making an int field in MySQL and sets it to AI. I made sure I didn't put the GenerationType.AUTO into the class, but to no avail.

What's even more peculiar is that when I try to change the data type of the column directly in MySQL, it won't let me.

Anyone had a similar problem or has a quick solution?

Hibernate: 4.3.6.Final
MySQL: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, 5.1.31 connector

```
package com.online_exchange.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author re5pect
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactionrequest")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Transactionrequest.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Transactionrequest t")
    ,
    @NamedQuery(name = "Transactionrequest.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM Transactionrequest t WHERE t.id = :id")
    ,
    @NamedQuery(name = "Transactionrequest.findByAmount", query = "SELECT t FROM Transactionrequest t WHERE t.amount = :amount")
    ,
    @NamedQuery(name = "Transactionrequest.findByRate", query = "SELECT t FROM Transactionrequest t WHERE t.rate = :rate")})
public class Transactionrequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private double amount;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "rate")
    private double rate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private User client;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transactionRequest")
    private Collection<Transactionoffer> transactionofferCollection;
    @Transient
    private boolean alreadyOffered = false;

    public Transactionrequest() {
    }

    public Transactionrequest(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Transactionrequest(String id, double amount, double rate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public User getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(User client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Transactionoffer> getTransactionofferCollection() {
        return transactionofferCollection;
    }

    public void setTransactionofferCollection(Collection<Transactionoffer> transactionofferCollection) {
        this.transactionofferCollection = transactionofferCollection;
    }

    public void addTransactionoffer(Transactionoffer offer) {
        this.transactionofferCollection.add(offer);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Transactionrequest)) {
            return false;
        }
        Transactionrequest other = (Transactionrequest) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.online_exchange.model.Transactionrequest[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    /**
     * @return the alreadyOffered
     */
    public boolean isAlreadyOffered() {
        return alreadyOffered;
    }

    /**
     * @param alreadyOffered the alreadyOffered to set
     */
    public void setAlreadyOffered(boolean alreadyOffered) {
        this.alreadyOffered = alreadyOffered;
    }

    public void purge() {
        this.setClient(null);
        this.setTransactionofferCollection(null);
    }

    public void prune() {
        this.getClient().purge();
        if(this.getTransactionofferCollection() != null){
            for(Transactionoffer offer : this.getTransactionofferCollection()){
                offer.purge();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the bit from MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactionrequest` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `amount` double NOT NULL,
   `rate` double NOT NULL,
   `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK_92xewutta5u8mr2ds6iqy20ga` (`client_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_92xewutta5u8mr2ds6iqy20ga` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `app_user` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Post your code and the generated table definition instead of describing them.

Comment: Java:

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

MySQL (automatically generated script - supposedly by Hibernate):
CREATE TABLE `transactionrequest` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `amount` double NOT NULL,
   `rate` double NOT NULL,
   `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK_92xewutta5u8mr2ds6iqy20ga` (`client_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_92xewutta5u8mr2ds6iqy20ga` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `app_user` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Post **all** the relevant code in the question, properly formatted. Not small sections in a comment.

Comment: Edited OP with the the relevant class, as well as the MySQL bit

Comment: What version of Hibernate and which MySQL dialect are you using?

Comment: Hibernate: 4.3.6.Final

MySQL: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, connector - 5.1.31